# xcode inapp purchase, best way to offer free purchases for critics etc

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am about to launch an app that will have several 'in app purchases'.

What I want to do is have a way that I can offer a small number of free 'in app purchases' to select people such as critics etc.

Is there a way within the apple framework to do this or if not what other approach I can take.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Apple does not provide the ability to offer in-app purchases for free nor does Apple provide anything like promo codes for in-app purchases. Both are major problems, in my opinion, with in-app purchases.

You can write your own "promo code" like feature where you give a code to a user that can then be entered into your app. Your app will then need a way to validate the code so it can't be used more than once.

Another option is to offer a paid version of your app that includes all of the in-app purchases based features but without the need to do in-app purchases. Then you can offer real promo codes to people for the paid version of the app. Of course this has its own problems such as maintaining and deploying two versions of essentially the same app.